# Ubuntu Server 12.1 CDrom issues after install

Tags: installation, server

After successfully installing Ubuntu Server 12.1 from an ISO on a cd. Now the problem is this: Cdrom can be located manually, how ever it says that the DIR doesn't exist. I get this:

```
root@PXE:/dev# cd /cdrom/
```

-bash: cd: /cdrom/: No such file or directory

I know where the CD is, but we can not CD into the DIR. We are trying to set up a DHCP server on a dell poweredge R210. THE DHCP is working.

However my only issue is that i can not get Ubuntu Server to recognize the CDROM to gain access to ONE file i need which is pxelinux.o

If you need more info let me know.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but is de CD mounted ?

Comment: Yes it looks like you are in the /dev directory and are under the impression that you can access the contents of the CDROM by cd'ing to /dev/cdrom (which would be `cd cdrom` by the way - no leading `/` before the `cdrom`) - that won't work, since /dev/cdrom is the raw (unmounted) block device.

Comment: Alright so I managed to get it to mount, however I'm facing a new problem. root@PXE:~# mount /dev/cdrom* /media/cdrom mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only I'm at a lose as to how to make it read-write. If it helps the server is a Dell PowerEdge R210 ii. As its pretty apparent that I'm a little newbie. Thanks by the way, you got me past my previous problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, devices must be *mounted* to a location in the filesystem before they become accessible for reading or writing. In the case of Ubuntu desktop editions, CDROMs are typically automounted, but in the case of the server editions they must be mounted manually. The general format for that is

```
mount [-fnrsvw] [-t vfstype] [-o options] device dir
```

where `device` is the *block device* (typically `/dev/cdrom` for CDROM devices) and `dir` is the filesystem location where you want the device to be mounted (the *mountpoint*). In the case of CDROM devices, the `vfstype` (filesystem type) should be detected automatically, and other options are probably not needed, so it should be sufficient to do

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
```

so long as the mountpoint `/media/cdrom` exists - if not you can create it with

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom
```

You will then be able to access the CDROM contents by going to `/media/cdrom` i.e.

```
cd /media/cdrom
```

Of course you are free to mount at `/cdrom` instead of `/media/cdrom` if you prefer.